# function that gets an Int and returns a list

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I have an exercise in Haskell where I need to create various types.The first type is called Finite which is defined like this:

```
type Finite a = [a]
```

and then I need to return a singleton which is defined like this

```
singleF :: a -> Finite a
```

so I implemented it like so:

```
single n = [n]
```

Then later I create another type

```
type Enumeration a = Int -> Finite a
```

then I need to reimplement the singleton function

```
singleE :: a -> Enumeration a
```

In my understanding the type `Enumeration` is a synonym for a function from an Int to a list of type `a`, but I can't understand how exactly I can implement that.

From the exercise (the previous type 'Finite' is also referred to as a 'bucket'): `An enumeration is an infinite sequence of finite buckets, indexed by natural numbers`.

And the function single : `I suggest for simplicity that you put the sole item in bucket 0`, So I'm thinking that the int is the index of the bucket in the enumeration

Comment: There are many different ways to do that – what _properties_ do you wish the enumeration to have? (Should the integer determine the list length, the _maximum_ length, the starting position, ... or something completely different?)

Comment: @leftaroundabout from the exercise (the previous type 'Finite' is also referred to as a 'bucket'): `An enumeration is an infinite sequence of finite buckets, indexed by natural numbers.`  And the function single : `I suggest for simplicity that you put the sole item in bucket 0`, So I'm thinking that the `int` is the index of the bucket in the enumeration.

Comment: You should edit that information into the question.

Comment: You would want `singleE :: Enumeration a` anyway.

Comment: @chepner the exercise clearly states that singleE is defined as I wrote above `singleE :: a -> Enumeration a`

Comment: You also said "reimplement the singleton function", which takes an Int and returns a singleton list. `singleE` as typed would take an Int and return a *function* that returns a list.

Comment: @chepner What I meant in "reimplement" is that I already implemented the singleton function for a bucket (Finite), and now have to do it for the `Enumeration` type. I think that I should take an Int and return a function, thats the part I don't understand completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
singleE :: a -> Enumeration a
singleE a 0 = singleF a
singleE _ _ = []

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let s=singleE 'a'
  print $ s 0
  print $ s 5
```

Gives

```
"a"
""
```

singleE gives you a function that takes an Int and returns a Finite. If you pass 0, you get a Finite with the single element, otherwise an empty one.

Comment: isn't `singleE` defined in such a way that its a function that takes an `a` and returns a function that returns a list?

Comment: Oh I think I understand now! I can substitute like so `singleE :: a -> Int -> Finite a` and that means I can now get the `Int` as well! thank you so much!

Comment: @EliBraginskiy An alternative could be to return a lambda: `singleE a = \n -> if n==0 then singleF a else []` (you can also use a `case` instead of `if`)

Comment: @chi I really like this solution. Is there any way to replace it with a `.` syntax instead though?

Comment: @EliBraginskiy Yes, but I don't think it's actually more readable. `singleE a = bool (singleF a) [] . (==0)` (import `Data.Bool` first). You could also remove the `a` argument, but things would get _really_ messy. Point-free style should not be followed at all costs.