# Not sure I understand this type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

Ok , So to continue [my previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684605/function-that-gets-an-int-and-returns-a-list) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688404/get-function-as-parameter-in-haskell), I have a type called `Enumeration`, It is described as

> Now, an enumeration is an infinite sequence of finite buckets,
>   indexed by natural numbers

And defined as so:

```
> type Nat = Int 
> type Enumeration a = Nat -> Finite a
```

this is a `Finite Bucket`

```
> type Finite a = [a]
```

So if I understand correctly, an `Enumeration` is something like a list of lists? it is a function from an Int to a list, and it should take an int like an index, and return a list.

But what I can't understand is if it is indeed a list of lists, where does it store it "lists" so it can later return them with the `index` I provide.

I've defined some functions over this `Enumeration` type, but I'm not sure if they are correct because I'm not sure if I understand what `Enumeration` really is.

For example:

Define a function to make a singleton enumeration.
I suggest for simplicity that you put the sole item in bucket 0.

```
> singleE' :: a -> Enumeration a
> singleE' a 0 = singleF a
```

Define mapping over enumerations:

```
> imapE :: (a -> b) -> Enumeration a -> Enumeration b
> imapE f g = (imapF f) . g
```

Define disjoint union of enumerations:

> For simplicity, you can do this bucket by bucket: the items in bucket i of the result enumeration should be drawn from buckets i of
>   the two argument enumerations.

```
> plusE :: Enumeration a -> Enumeration b -> Enumeration (Either a b)
> plusE f g = \n -> [Left x | x <- f n] ++ [Right y | y <- g n]
```

Define cartesian product of enumerations

> This is trickier, because you can’t do it bucket by bucket any more,
>   as you did for plusE (why not?). The simplest technique is to perform
>   a kind of convolution: the items in bucket i of the result enumeration
>   should be con- structed from those in bucket j of the first argument
>   and in bucket k of the second, where j + k = i.

```
> timesE :: Enumeration a -> Enumeration b -> Enumeration (a,b)
> timesE f g = \n -> timesF (f n) (g n)
```

So my questions are:

1. Did I understand the type of `Enumeration` correctly
2. If I did, are the functions I defined correct?

Comment: maybe you should at least link to your previous question ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684605/function-that-gets-an-int-and-returns-a-list) right?) - but depending on if your `imapF` and `singleF` are correct this seems to be ok - maybe you could argue that you want to return empty buckets for ever other integer in `singleE'` (not making it partial) but that might depend on your specs here

Comment: What do you mean by _correct_? What you say makes sense and the functions typecheck and everything, so I'd say _there's nothing wrong_ here. But to discuss whether it's _right_, you'd need to specify what you're actually trying to achieve. — What I'd remark already is that this kind of container will exhibit subpar performance in many circumstances, but for some applications it may do pretty well.

Comment: @Carsten @leftaroundabout I've updated the question, with instructions I've got on plusE, and another function called timesE, because of the instructions I feel like I didn't understand the type of `Enumeration` correctly.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, @EliBraginskiy I have the feeling whomever is giving these exercises is trying to build up to some constructive proofs that sum types and product types preserve enumerability/countability, e.g. prove from enumerations of the natural numbers that you can enumerate rational numbers. That's probably why you have `k + j = i` (the classic counting method of rational numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove that `Enumeration a` is (mostly) isomorphic to lists of lists.
The "isomorphism" is given by the following functions:

```
enumerationToLists :: Enumeration a -> [[a]]
enumerationToLists f = map f [0..]

listsToEnumeration :: [[a]] -> Enumeration a
listsToEnumeration xss i = head $ drop i (xss++empties)
```

Where:

```
empties :: [[a]]
empties = []:empties
```

Thanks to referential transparency we can use "equational reasoning" as done in mathematics to prove that they form indeed an "isomorphism"

Proof that `listsToEnumeration . enumerationToLists = id`:

```
    (listsToEnumeration . enumerationToLists) f
by definition of .
    = listsToEnumeration (enumerationToLists f)
by definition of enumerationToLists
    = listsToEnumeration (map f [0..])
by definition of map
    = listsToEnumeration [f 0, f 1, f 2, ...]
by definition of listsToEnumeration
    = \i -> head $ drop i ([f 0, f 1, f 2, ...]++empties)
concatenation of infinite lists
    = \i -> head $ drop i [f 0, f 1, f 2, ...]
by definition of drop and of the argument
    = \i -> head $ [f i, f (i+1), f (i+2), ...]
by definition of head
    = \i -> f i
eta reduction  (i.e. \x -> f x = f)
    = f
```

And now that, given `xss = [xs1, xs2, ..., xsN]` and `empties = []:empties`, we have `(enumerationToLists . listsToEnumeration) (xss++empties) = xss++empties`

```
    (enumerationToLists . listsToEnumeration) (xss++empties)
by definition of .
    = enumerationToLists (listsToEnumeration (xss++empties))
by definition of listsToEnumeration
    = enumerationToLists (\i -> head $ drop i (xss++empties++empties))
concatenation of infinite lists
    = enumerationToLists (\i -> head $ drop i (xss++empties))
by definition of empties
    = enumerationToLists (\i -> head $ drop i [xs1, xs2, ..., xsN, [], [], ...])
by definition of enumerationToLists
    = map (\i -> head $ drop i [xs1, xs2, ..., xsN, [], [], ...]) [0..]
by definition of map
    = let f = (\i -> head $ drop i [xs1, xs2, ..., xsN, [], [], ...]) in [f 0, f 1, ...]
by definition of f
    = [head $ drop 0 [xs1, xs2, ..., xsN, [], ...], head $ drop 1 [xs1, xs2, ..., xsN, [], ...], ...]
by definition of drop
    = [head [xs1, xs2, xsN, [], ...], head [xs2, ... xsN, [], ..], ..., head [xsN, [],...], head [[], ...], ..]
by definition of head
    = [xs1, xs2, ..., xsN, [], [], ...]
by definition of xss, empties and ++
    = xss ++ empties
```

Obviously we have assumed that `Enumeration a` is total (it should return `[]` for "non defined indices"). The two functions above are an isomorphism if we restrict to infinite lists of list, otherwise it only holds "up to `++empties`" (if `xss` is infinite we have `xss = xss++empties` because we will never be able to access the empties part).

So if you care to maintain this "isomorphism" you should make sure that all your functions are total (looking at `singleE'`...), but except for this they look fine.

I hope the example above gives you an hint on how to reason about whether or not the functions you define are correct.

Comment: If I understand, `enumerationToLists` should give you the same list for every number? so you get an infinite list of lists, but they are all the same list? (As I wrote in question 3)

Comment: @EliBraginskiy No. For each index `i` it returns whatever value `f i` is.  For example an enumeration could be `f = \i -> case i of 0 -> []; 1 -> [1], 2 -> [2], _ -> []` and `enumerationToLists f = [[], [1], [2], [], [], ....]`   Take *any* list of lists, i.e. `[[1,2,3], [1,2], [3]]` then `listsToEnumeration [[1,2,3], [1,2], [3]]` returns an equivalent `Enumeration`.   So definitely `Enumeration` is just a different representation for lists of lists, and the formal proof is in this answer: there is a bijection between the two.

Comment: @EliBraginskiy I don't know. I didn't read that tutorial and thus I have no idea what the author  wants you to do.  Obviously if you impose that an `Enumeration` is always empty except for the index `0` you get something that resembles flat lists... with a lot of redundant stuff. Is this text freely available somewhere?

Comment: Just as a side note, you could have used `repeat []` instead of writing the function `empties`.